# The mean and variance of the sample median

Tags: probability, probability-theory, sampling

The population and the median of a sample sized $2k+1$ should have the same mean and variance. Why is that? Will the result still be so tidy for a sample sized $2k$?

Comment: In your first sentence, do you mean "population mean"?

Comment: @MattBrenneman : I'm parsing it like this: the population has a certain mean, and the median of a sample of size $2k+1$ has a certain mean (i.e. expected value over all possible samples).  And those two expected values are equal.  In other words, if $X$ is the value assigned to a random member of the population, then $\mu=\mathbb EX$ is the population mean, and $\operatorname{median}(X_1,\ldots,X_{2k+1})$ is the sample median, and the claim is that $\mathbb E(\operatorname{median}(X_1,\ldots,X_{2k+1}))$ must then also be equal to that same number $\mu$.

Comment: @AlexSu : Suppose $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are the mean and variance of the population.  Let $X_1,\ldots,X_{2k+1}$ be an i.i.d. sample.  Then $\mathbb E(\operatorname{median}(X_1,\ldots,X_{2k+1}))=\mu$ but $\operatorname{var}(\operatorname{median}(X_1,\ldots,X_{2k+1}))\ne\sigma^2$.  On the contrary, the latter variance will be much smaller than $\sigma^2$, although not as small as $\sigma^2/(2k+1)$, which is the variance of the sample mean.

Comment: For a sample of size $2k$ it is somewhat conventional to regard the mean of the two middle values as the sample median.  The expected value of that statistic will still be $\mu$.  I don't know what the variance is, beyond the fact that it's much smaller than $\sigma^2$ but bigger than $\sigma^2/(2k)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Could you give me a hint on how to calculate the variance of the median? Because in my textbook this is used as an example to illustrate the concept "efficient estimate". And there it claims that the variance shall be $\sigma^2$

Comment: Which book? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I think I will post an argument from symmetry for the proposition that $\mathbb E(\operatorname{median}(X_1,\ldots,X_{2k+1}))=\mu$.  But I'm going to have to think about how to phrase it efficiently.

Comment: One case in which I think the sample median would be better than the sample mean as an estimate of a location parameter is with the Cauchy distributions.  Those do not even have an expected value, let alone a finite variance.

Comment: @MichaelHardy actually it won't be published until next year. It's written by a professor in our school. And under the claim that the variance is $\sigma^2$ it writes "consider why!"

Comment: @MichaelHardy in the book "efficient estimate" is defined as an unbiased estimate that have relatively smaller variance

Comment: Can you quote verbatim the statement about the variance?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think my textbook is wrong. I referred to the Spiegel-Schiller-Srinivasan book and it says the standard error of the median is $\sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}$

Comment: Why do you think the median has mean $\mu$?

Comment: @Did mainly because it should not be larger or less than $\mu$ lol

Comment: Did you try to check this hunch in some concrete settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The population and the median of a sample sized $2k+1$ should have the same mean and variance.

Should they, really? To check this, let us compute the mean of the median $M$ of a sample of size $3$ from the distribution with density $f:x\mapsto ax^{a-1}\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt1}$, for some positive $a$, and with CDF $F$.

The distribution of $M$ has density $6fF(1-F)$ and $F(x)=x^a$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$ hence
$$
E[M]=\int 6xf(x)F(x)(1-F(x))\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1 6a(x^{2a}-x^{3a})\,\mathrm dx=\frac{6a^2}{(2a+1)(3a+1)},
$$
while the mean of the population is
$$
E[X]=\int xf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1ax^{a}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{a}{a+1},
$$
hence $E[M]\ne E[X]$ unless $a=1$.